# How to insert into an SQL table values from var_char($_POST) and dropdowns made with for loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

As mentioned in title above, I want to save data from var_char(_$POST) in sql table and data from dropdown within a for loop. I use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_GET['action'] == 'schedule'){
     $sdate = $_POST['start-date'];
     $dateQ = "INSERT INTO schedule (schedule_id,user_email,date,morning,afternoon,evening) VALUES ('','$email','$sdate','$morningId','$afternoonId','$eveningId')";
            if($dateQ) {
                echo 'success';
            }
            else {
                echo 'fail';
            }
```

Although it returned success, the table is still empty. Even if I get this right how can I insert into the table values from a for loop? like this:

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $correctDays; $i++) { 
?>

<div>
    <hr>
        <h2>Schedule for day <?php echo $i; ?></h2>
    <hr>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Pick an activity from 09:00-14:00:</h3>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <select name="morning<?php echo $i; ?>" style="text-align:center;">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($morningR)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['sightname']. '</option>';
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($morningR, 0);
    ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Pick an activity from 14:00-18:00:</h3>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <select name="afternoon<?php echo $i; ?>" style="text-align:center;">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($afternoonR)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['sightname'] . '</option>';
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($afternoonR, 0);
    ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Pick an activity from 18:00-24:00:</h3>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <select name="evening<?php echo $i; ?>" style="text-align:center;">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eveningR)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['sightname'] . '</option>';
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($eveningR, 0);
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: you never run the query; all you do is create a string that contains it

Comment: thanks man! what about the second part?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your query instead of storing the query in a variable as string.

First, you have to establish your database connection:

```
/** REPLACE THE ARGUMENTS WITH PROPER VALUE BELOW **/
$con = new mysqli("YourHost", "Username", "Password", "DatabaseName");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then, you can run your query:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_GET['action'] == 'schedule'){
    $sdate = $_POST['start-date'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO schedule (user_email, date, morning, afternoon, evening) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssiii", $email, $sdate, $morningId, $afternoonId, $eveningId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

By the way, where did you get the other variables (e.g., $email, $morningId, $afternoonId, $eveningId)? Hope you declared them prior to your INSERT query.

You can read more about prepared statement [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have all the variables right except $morningId,$afternoonId and $eveningId. I get them from the second part of the code through some dropdowns inside a for loop. My question is what to do to save all the dropdowns if the $correctdays are like 3 (and then of course the dropdowns will be 9 3 for each day).

Comment: @StavrosS Have you managed to make my answer (INSERT query) work?

Comment: I was helped from @nogad. I just put a mysqli_query and worked i just filled $morningId etc. with blanks cause i dont know how to get variables from dropdowns. Especially take them all inside the loop.

Comment: I am actually confused on your database structure and what you want to do with it so I can't help you right away with the displaying of your data.

Comment: My table is pretty simple actually. I have schedule_id(auto increment),user_email(which i get from a session),date(which i get from a date picker). And all other is picks from the user that uses the site. The result i want to have at every row of my table is the name of the user in the second column, the date that user picked at the third one and then the 3 activities that user picked from morning to evening. Then in a second row, if the user picked 2 days in the calendar, must be filled by the same user_id, the next date in calendar and then the activities that user picked from the 2nd day...